# React native changing variable in release build

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my app I have to use different API endpoints depending on the type of build.
Up till now I was always changing the api variable manually before each build, but now I wan't to see if this can be automated. Has anyone come up with a simple solution to this? I imagine this to be a check when the app is bundling, and if say the build is 'release', the api variable should be X.

Comment: There are very nice libraries that solve this problem, such as https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a good idea but you can use `__DEV__` global variable in JavaScript to determine if you're using React Native packager or not

```
const randomVar = __DEV__ ? 'devValue' : 'releaseVal';
```